# ServerReport Render timeout

Tags: c#, reporting-services, workflow, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm implementing serverReport in a CRM workflow.(not online version)

I set the workflow non-sandbox and I'm trying to implement a version of ServerReport i'm using in a C# Webservice.

This is the code: (the last line is the one throwing the exception)

```
        sr.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportServerBaseURL);
        sr.ReportPath = reportDir + reportName;

        // Credential to connect with CRM
        IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(username, password, "");
        sr.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;

        if (paramList != null && paramList.Count > 0)
        {
            bool isTimeout = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    sr.Timeout = 5000;
                    sr.Refresh();
                    sr.SetParameters(paramList);
                    isTimeout = false;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            if (isTimeout)
            {
                string message = "Report timeout";
                throw new Exception(message);
            }
        }
        sr.Timeout = 5000;
        sr.Refresh();
        string renderingString = null;

        switch (renderingMethod)
        {
            case RSRenderingMethods.PDF:
                renderingString = "PDF";
                break;
            case RSRenderingMethods.EXCEL:
                renderingString = "EXCEL";
                break;
            case RSRenderingMethods.PNG:
            case RSRenderingMethods.JPEG:
            case RSRenderingMethods.GIF:
            case RSRenderingMethods.TIFF:
                renderingString = "IMAGE";
                break;
        }
        //I'm reaching this point without problems, the format I'm using is PDF
        byte[] bytes = bytes = sr.Render(renderingString, null); //this line is throwing the exception
```

With the WebService I had no problems for the report rendering, and I don't know why this time I'm having them.

The report is about 30-40 rows, so it's not big at all. Might the problem be in something I'm doing?

Comment: what is in the exc stack trace?
and/or debug the code and pause the process to see where it is waiting.

Comment: @Dexion I'll add it in the question, I wrote it as comment in the code portion, The last row is the one throwing the exception which simply is: The operation has timed out

Comment: try to step in the render method to see what happens

Comment: @Dexion I don't honestly know how to do it, it is a method from MetaData. I don't think it is debuggable

Comment: reflector or dotpeek can help you